# How to make a div take all the remaining space when the parent has no fixed size?

Tags: html, css

I have a #container div that has no fixed size (the content is PHP generated) and I have a #left-pannel that I want it to take the height of the whole parent height:100%; has no effect until I fix the size of the #container which can't be a solution because the content can't be the same (and i have no control over it) I am just supposed to make the #left-pannel take the whole height.

PS: I don't know what else I should provide so if you need any info comment.

Comment: Not much to go on, but maybe take a quick look at http://960.gs and see if that might fit your needs

Comment: #dave i said i have no control on the content SO I CAN NOT change the structure, i just need to handle CSS

Comment: If you can edit the CSS, do you also have the ability to edit/amend the JavaScript? I don't think that this can be solved in just css, except, perhaps with [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/), which is more of a hack/visual trick.

Comment: i can add javascript, i just can't change the structure of HTML

Comment: and fixing the size of anything is a bigger problem, cuz the content will never be fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#leftpanel {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
}
```